# canvas drawing slow in firefox

Tags: html, html5-canvas

i am working on a plugin you can see in my fiddle, problem is when we draw in firefox it slows down but fine in google Chrome. any help??

BTW using two canvas, one is for drawing area to save it as image later. check fiddle

```
context.beginPath();
newcontext.beginPath();
// If dragging then draw a line between the two points
if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
    context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
    newcontext.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
} else {
    // The x position is moved over one pixel so a circle even if not dragging
    context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
    newcontext.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
}
context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
newcontext.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
// Set the drawing color
if (clickTool[i] === "eraser") {
    //context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; // To erase instead of draw over with white
    context.strokeStyle = 'white';
    newcontext.strokeStyle = 'white';
} else {
    //context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // To erase instead of draw over with white
    context.strokeStyle = clickColor[i];
    newcontext.strokeStyle = clickColor[i];
}

context.lineCap = "round";
context.lineJoin = "round";
context.lineWidth = radius;
context.stroke();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aV6bg/

Comment: A very similar question I had but no luck. I wish if anybody can provide some answer to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940057/do-the-different-brwosers-have-different-priority-on-windows

Comment: just as the v8 engine is faster, the Chrome canvas is faster, as you can see in many jsperf. just this one for instance : http://jsperf.com/canvas-clear-speed, but have a look, in almost all situations Chrome has quite the lead. Maybe using libs like pixi.js you could speed up things on Browsers supporting webGL without rewriting your canvas code.

Comment: I have run into this issue as well with Canvas. And actually IE is fast as well. It is just firefox that seems to have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got rid of my second canvas which was for saving image, used below code to get drawing area rectangle so no noeed for second canvas anymore.

Now speed is better than before in Firefox 22(ubuntu).

```
function savePhoto() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var tempcanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var tempctx = tempcanvas.getContext("2d");
tempcanvas.width = 820;
tempcanvas.height = 675;
tempctx.drawImage(canvas, 90, 131,790, 680,0, 0,  820, 680);
var dataUrl = tempcanvas.toDataURL();
alert(dataUrl);
}

//Ajax Request to save image to folder For drawings page
var request = $.ajax({
url: "<?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'/canvas?wcpdx=ajax-handler'; ?>",
type: "POST",
data: { 'rawimage': dataUrl }
});
request.done(function(msg) {
alert( 'success = '+msg );
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

works great :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing a lot of computations and drawing for something that could be obtained in a much simpler way.

In other words it's not Firefox that is slow... it's just that Chrome is blazing fast :-D

An alternative approach would be for example having a partially transparent image displayed by the browser on top of a canvas and then your drawing operations are performed on the canvas directly without special masking.

What this could allow is seeing the painting through the mask without having to do complex clipping manipulations.

Those operations could be done for real on a single canvas only when the user asks to export the picture as a png if this is something you need to provide.

To see an example of this approach in action [check this out](http://raksy.dyndns.org/crayons.html)

The [source code](http://raksy.dyndns.org/crayons.lisp) is in lisp but it shouldn't be too hard to read (the full program is only 116 lines)